# How does number precision affect performance in JavaScript, or does it?

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, numbers

In JavaScript, there's only one type for all different kinds of numbers. Does the amount of decimals in the numbers used (precision) affect performance especially in JavaScript? If it does, how?

How about saving numbers in MongoDB: Do precise numbers take more space than less precise ones?

Comment: You can find these answers with some experiments. I think floats and integers do have different performance but not more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the amount of decimals in the numbers used (precision) affect performance especially in JavaScript? If it does, how?

No. The number type in JavaScript is a 64-bit floating-point value with base 2 and always has the same *precision*. The computer works on that data bit by bit and it doesn't matter whether that data represents something that looks simple to a human like `1.0` or something seemingly complicated like `123423.5645632`. In fact, for base 2 floats, the 'human' values are just as 'hard', because `1.1` is truly represented by a much longer number (sth. like `1.10000000000000054`). All this doesn't matter, because the computer truly operates on 64 ones and zeros. There are always some arcane exceptions in floating point, but those usually don't matter in practice.

> How about saving numbers in MongoDB: Do precise numbers take more space than less precise ones?

Decimal numbers are stored as doubles (64bit), and it doesn't matter whether that is `1.0` or `1.1221234423`. Again, the number of bits is constant for these data types.

The same is true for ints, but MongoDB has support for both 32- and 64-bit ints. So `NumberLong` is indeed larger than regular 32-bit ints and just as large as doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no.  There are some possible performance implications when a number doesn't fit in a 31b signed int.

[A tour of V8: object representation](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation) explains

> According to the spec, all numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit floating point doubles. We frequently work with integers though, so V8 represents numbers with 31-bit signed integers whenever possible (the low bit is always 0; this helps the garbage collector distinguish numbers from pointers). So objects with the fast small integers elements kind only contain this type of number. **If we want to store a fractional number or a larger integer or a special value like -0, then we need to upgrade the array to fast doubles. This involves a potentially expensive copy-and-convert operation, but it doesn't happen often in practice. fast doubles objects are still pretty fast because all of the numbers are stored in an unboxed representation.** If we want to store any other kind of value, e.g., a string or an object, we must upgrade to a general array of fast elements.